# Attempted import error: 'ReadableStream' is not exported from './streams_polyfill'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I was trying to extract text from pdf using react and I followed this [procedure](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/405/how-to-convert-pdf-to-text-extract-text-from-pdf-with-javascript).

I've got the following error:

> ./src/pdf.js/src/shared/util.js
>
> Attempted import error: 'ReadableStream' is not exported from > './streams_polyfill'.

Take a look at this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1g4NI.png) for my logic. [Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LL81.png) another screenshot.